# Actually i'm trying to get a notification in odoo16 but this error is coming up

Tags: python, notifications, odoo-16

```
TypeError: _sendone() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

commonutilos.py

```
from odoo import api, _, fields
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError


class CommonUtils(object):

    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialise the class'''

    CREDIT_COUNT = 18

    
    def add_followers(self, res):
        res.message_subscribe(partner_ids=res.env.user.partner_id.ids)

    def show_warning_message(self, res, message):
        res.env['bus.bus']._sendone(
            (res._cr.dbname, 'res.partner', res.env.user.partner_id.id),
            {'type': 'user_connection', 'title': _('Credit Hrs'), 'message': message, 'sticky': True,
           =
                'submit_date': False,
                'approved_uid': False,
                'approved_date': False
            })

    def update_submit(self, res):
        for val in res:
            val.update({
                'state': 'submit',
                'submit_uid': res.env.user,
                'submit_date': fields.Datetime.now(),
            })

    def update_approve(self, res):
        for val in res:
            val.update({
                'state': 'approve',
                'approved_uid': res.env.user,
                'approved_date': fields.Datetime.now()
            })
```

I tried changing the starting lines as sendone and sendmany but there is no luck so i keep trying but none of them has any answer